# ¿Cómo imprimir SP con parámetros en PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, stored-procedure, parametros

espero que disculpen si la pregunta ofende, pero soy nuevo programando con procedimientos almacenados, el tema en cuestión es que mi código funciona, mas no imprime nada y no manda ningún error

El código para mi conexión es:

```
<?php
    $servidor="localhost";
    $bd="centroidiomas";
    $user="sa";
    $pw="12345";

    try{
        $cnx = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servidor;Database=$bd","$user","$pw");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Error al conectar a la bd" . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

El que tengo para mi impresión es:

```
<?php
              $nom=$_GET['nombre'];
              $apa=$_GET['apa'];
              $ama=$_GET['ama'];

              $codigo=$_GET['cod'];
              $nombre=$_GET['nom'];
              $idioma=$_GET['idioma_certificado'];
              $nivel=$_GET['nivel_certificado'];
              $nexp=$_GET['num_exp'];
              $nvou=$_GET['num_vouch'];
              $autor=$_GET['autor_certificado'];

              $sql2 ="exec dbo.sp_ImprimeCertificado '$codigo','$idioma'";
              $stmt2 = $cnx->prepare($sql2);
              //    $stmt2->bindParam('@codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              //    $stmt2->bindParam('@idioma', $idioma, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt2->execute(array());
              $rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              $row_count2 = $stmt2->rowCount();

              foreach ($rows2 as $row2)
                      {
                        echo '

                              '.$codigo.'"\n/n"
                              '.numromanos($row2['CICLO']).'
                              '.$row2['NOTA'].'
                              '.numaletras($row2['NOTA']).'
                              '.$row2['FECHA_FORMATEADA'].'
                            ';
                      }
            ?>
```

mi procedimiento almacenado es:

```
USE [centroidiomas]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_ImprimeCertificado]
@codigo as char(9),
@idioma as varchar(3)

AS
BEGIN

WITH CTE_MATRICULA AS
(
SELECT CODIGO, (case
        WHEN CICLO= 'I' then CAST('1' AS INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'II' then CAST('2' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'III' then CAST('3' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'IV' then CAST('4' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'V' then CAST('5' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VI' then CAST('6' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VII' then CAST('7' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'VIII' then CAST('8' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'IX' then CAST('9' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'X' then CAST('10' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XI' then CAST('11' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XII' then CAST('12' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIII' then CAST('13' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIV' then CAST('14' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XV' then CAST('15' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVI' then CAST('16' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVII' then CAST('17' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XVIII' then CAST('18' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XIX' then CAST('19' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XX' then CAST('20' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXI' then CAST('21' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXII' then CAST('22' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXIII' then CAST('23' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXIV' then CAST('24' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXV' then CAST('25' as INTEGER)
        WHEN CICLO= 'XXVI' then CAST('26' as INTEGER)
        END) AS CICLO, NOTA, fecha
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO, CICLO ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS RN
    FROM CI_MATRICULA
  WHERE codigo =@codigo and idioma=@idioma and nota>=15
)
SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, CONVERT (char(8),fecha, 3) as FECHA_FORMATEADA
INTO #TEMP_MATRICULA
FROM CTE_MATRICULA
WHERE RN = 1

SELECT CODIGO, CICLO, NOTA, FECHA_FORMATEADA
FROM #TEMP_MATRICULA
order by CICLO

END;
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me imprima los valores de la consulta ya jalando las variables de get y haciéndole trabajar al SP con ellos.
No sé si sea necesario trabajar con bindParam, busqué información de la función de php sin embargo no logro entenderlo.

he probado añadiendo estas lineas y aun no me imprime nada:

```
$stmt2->bindParam('@codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt2->bindParam('@idioma', $idioma, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Agradeceré bastante su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido a la comunidad, para poder ayudarte mejor te sugiero que coloques que conexión estas usandoe n $cnx, mysqli, sqlsrv, oci, simplemente pdo.. por otra parte veo que hace sun execute(array()), lo cual no creo que sea correcto, debería ser execute().

Comment: Gracias Jhoubert, respondiendo al comentario:
-$cnx es la que define mi conexión en PDO
- quité el execute(array()) por un execute() y no tuvo efecto alguno

Comment: No logro ver el error a simple vista, lo único que veo extraño por el momento es el `array()` de `$stmt2->execute(array());` quitalo para que quede: `$stmt2->execute();`

Comment: Con qué base de datos trabajas? Procura siempre indicarlo usando la etiqueta relevante. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir la etiqueta

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás escribiendo una consulta preparada realmente.

En las consultas preparadas tienes que poner marcadores de `:nombre` o de posición `?`.

Veamos un ejemplo usando marcadores de `:nombre`:

```
$sql2 ="exec dbo.sp_ImprimeCertificado :codigo, :idioma";
#Preparamos la consulta
$stmt2 = $cnx->prepare($sql2);
```

> **Atención:** En la consulta no se usa el signo `$`, ni se usan las comillas simples `'`. Ahí sólo **ponemos un marcador**, es como decir
>   al manejador: *ahí va un dato, luego te lo paso con `bindParam` para
>   que ningún hacker te engañe :)*

Y, como lo prometido es deuda, ahora le pasas los datos:

```
$stmt2->bindParam(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':idioma', $idioma, PDO::PARAM_STR);

#Finalmente ejecutamos
$stmt2->execute(array());
```

> **Atención también:** Aquí no tienes que usar `@`, sino el mismo marcador que usaste en la consulta preparada por cada dato. Lo que le
>   dices ahí al manejador es: *el dato para el marcador `:codigo` es
>   `$codigo` y el dato para el marcador `:idioma` es `$idioma`*.

Si quieres, puedes también escribir la consulta así:

```
$sql2 ="exec dbo.sp_ImprimeCertificado ?, ?";
```

Y pasar los datos en el `execute` en forma de array:

```
#Preparamos la consulta
$stmt2 = $cnx->prepare($sql2);
#Finalmente ejecutamos
$stmt2->execute(array($codigo,$idioma));
```

Ambas formas son válidas. En este segundo caso no necesitas usar `bindParam`, el binding se hace por medio del `execute`.

Haciendo eso debería funcionar.